# `uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?

Tags: date, parsing, datetime, date-formatting, java-time

The [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class documentation says about its formatting codes for the year:

> u       year                        year              2004; 04
>
> y       year-of-era                 year              2004; 04
>
> …
>
> **Year:** The count of letters determines the minimum field width below which padding is used. If the count of letters is two, then a reduced two digit form is used. For printing, this outputs the rightmost two digits. For parsing, this will parse using the base value of 2000, resulting in a year within the range 2000 to 2099 inclusive. If the count of letters is less than four (but not two), then the sign is only output for negative years as per SignStyle.NORMAL. Otherwise, the sign is output if the pad width is exceeded, as per SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD.

No other mention of “era”.

So what is the difference between these two codes, `u` versus `y`, `year` versus `year-of-era`?

When should I use something like this pattern `uuuu-MM-dd` and when `yyyy-MM-dd` when working with dates in Java?

Seems that example code written by those in the know use `uuuu`, but why?

Other formatting classes such as the legacy [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) have only `yyyy`, so I am confused why java.time brings this `uuuu` for “year of era”.

Comment: The pattern letters in java.time.* are based on CLDR/LDML: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: **For future visitors:** Apart from the answers on this page, you can also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573 for some more explanation and examples.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Within the scope of `java.time`-package, we can say:

- It is **safer to use "u" instead of "y"** because [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) will otherwise insist on having an era in combination with "y" (= year-of-era). So using "u" would avoid some possible unexpected exceptions in strict formatting/parsing. See also this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41103603/issue-with-datetimeparseexception-when-using-strict-resolver-style). Another minor thing which is improved by "u"-symbol compared with "y" is printing/parsing negative gregorian years (in far past).
- Otherwise we can clearly state that **using "u" instead of "y" breaks long-standing habits in Java-programming**. It is also not intuitively clear that "u" denotes any kind of year because a) the first letter of the English word "year" is not in agreement with this symbol and b) `SimpleDateFormat` has used "u" for a different purpose since Java-7 ([ISO-day-number-of-week](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)). Confusion is guaranteed - for ever?
- We should also see that **using eras (symbol "G") in context of ISO is in general dangerous if we consider historic dates**. If "G" is used with "u" then both fields are unrelated to each other. And if "G" is used with "y" then the formatter is satisfied but still uses proleptic gregorian calendar when the historic date mandates different calendars and date-handling.

### Background information:

When developing and integrating the [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) (`java.time`-packages) the designers decided to use [Common Locale Data Repository (CLDR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Locale_Data_Repository)/LDML-spec as the base of pattern symbols in `DateTimeFormatter`. The symbol "u" was already defined in CLDR as proleptic gregorian year, so this meaning was adopted to new upcoming JSR-310 (but not to `SimpleDateFormat` because of backwards compatibility reasons).

However, this decision to follow CLDR was not quite consistent because JSR-310 had also introduced new pattern symbols which didn't and still don't exist in CLDR, see also this old [CLDR-ticket](http://unicode.org/cldr/trac/ticket/5506). The suggested symbol "I" was changed by CLDR to "VV" and finally overtaken by JSR-310, including [new symbols "x" and "X"](http://cldr.unicode.org/development/development-process/design-proposals/time-zone-offset-patterns). But "n" and "N" still don't exist in CLDR, and since this old ticket is closed, it is not clear at all if CLDR will ever support it in the sense of JSR-310. Furthermore, the ticket does not mention the symbol "p" (padding instruction in JSR-310, but not defined in CLDR). **So we have still no perfect agreement between pattern definitions across different libraries and languages.**

And about "y": We should also not overlook the fact that CLDR associates this year-of-era with at least some kind of mixed Julian/Gregorian year and not with the proleptic gregorian year as JSR-310 does (leaving the oddity of negative years aside). So no perfect agreement between CLDR and JSR-310 here, too.

Comment: @hephestos This is off-topic, but the replacement for `System.out.write_line_and_dont_use_again_println()` is simply `System.out.print()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I ran into this question the first time I tried ResolverStyle.STRICT

Answer (score 43):

In the javadoc section [Patterns for Formatting and Parsing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) for `DateTimeFormatter` it lists the following 3 relevant symbols:

```
Symbol  Meaning        Presentation  Examples
------  -------        ------------  -------
 G       era            text          AD; Anno Domini; A
 u       year           year          2004; 04
 y       year-of-era    year          2004; 04
```

Just for comparison, these other symbols are easy enough to understand:

```
 D       day-of-year    number        189
 d       day-of-month   number        10
 E       day-of-week    text          Tue; Tuesday; T
```

The `day-of-year`, `day-of-month`, and `day-of-week` are obviously the *day* within the given scope (year, month, week).

So, `year-of-era` means the *year* within the given scope (era), and right above it `era` is shown with an example value of `AD` (the other value of course being `BC`).

`year` is the *signed* year, where year `0` is `1 BC`, year `-1` is `2 BC`, and so forth.

To illustrate: When was [Julius Caesar assassinated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Julius_Caesar)?

- March 15, 44 BC (using pattern `MMMM d, y GG`)
- March 15, -43      (using pattern `MMMM d, u`)

The distinction will of course only matter if year is zero or negative, and since that is rare, most people don't care, even though they should.

**Conclusion:** If you use `y` you should also use `G`. Since `G` is rarely used, the correct year symbol is `u`, not `y`, otherwise a non-positive year will show incorrectly.

This is known as [defensive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming):

> Defensive programming is a form of defensive design intended to **ensure the continuing function** of a piece of software **under unforeseen circumstances**.

---

Note that `DateTimeFormatter` is consistent with [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
Letter  Date or Time Component  Presentation  Examples
------  ----------------------  ------------  --------
G       Era designator          Text          AD
y       Year                    Year          1996; 96
```

Negative years has always been a problem, and they now fixed it by adding `u`.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that a) `DateTimeFormatter` is not clever enough to handle y like u if there is no era and b) usage of y and G for historic dates is wrong because there is no support for Julian calendar and other historic anomalies in the scope of `java.time.*`. c) It is also a general problem of CLDR-format symbols that these symbols often start with an unexpected letter (see u versus y where latter indicates the first letter of word "year").

Comment: About consistency between `DateTimeFormatter` and `SimpleDateFormat`: No there is no consistency, just look how the symbol "u" is handled in both libraries. It is different!!!

Answer (score 17):

### Long story short

1. For 99 % of purposes you can toss a coin, it will make no difference whether you use `yyyy` or `uuuu` (or whether you use `yy` or `uu` for 2-digit year).
2. It depends on what you want to happen in case a year earlier than 1 CE (1 AD) occurs. The point being that in 99 % of programs such a year will never occur.

Two other answers have already presented the facts of how `u` and `y` work very nicely, but I still felt something was missing, so I am contributing the slightly more opinion-based answer.

### For formatting

Assuming that you don’t expect a year before 1 CE to be formatted, the best thing you can do is to check this assumption and react appropriately in case it breaks. For example, depending on circumstances and requirements, you may print an error message or throw an exception. One very soft failure path might be to use a pattern with `y` (year of era) and `G` (era) in this case and a pattern with either `u` or `y` in the normal, current era case. Note that if you are printing the current date or the date your program was compiled,  you can be sure that it is in the common era and may opt to skip the check.

### For parsing

In many (most?) cases parsing also means validating meaning you have no guarantees what your input string looks like. Typically it comes from the user or from another system. An example: a date string comes as 2018-09-29. Here the choice between `uuuu` and `yyyy` should depend on what you want to happen in case the string contains a year of 0 or negative (e.g., `0000-08-17` or `-012-11-13`). Assuming that this would be an error, the immediate answer is: use `yyyy` in order for an exception to be thrown in this case. Still finer: use `uuuu` and after parsing perform a range check of the parsed date. The latter approach allows both for a finer validation and for a better error message in case of a validation error.

Special case (already mentioned by Meno Hochschild): If your formatter uses strict resolver style and contains `y` without `G`, parsing will *always* fail because strictly speaking year of era is ambiguous without era: 1950 might mean 1950 CE or 1950 BCE (1950 BC). So in this case you need `u` (or supplying a default era, this is possible through a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`).

### Long story short again

Explicit range check of your dates, specifically your years, is better than relying on the choice between `uuuu` and `yyyy` for catching unexpected very early years.

Answer (score 2):

Short comparison, if you need strict parsing:
Examples with invalid Date 31.02.2022

> System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT).parse("31.02.2022"));

prints "{MonthOfYear=2, DayOfMonth=31, YearOfEra=2022},ISO"

> System.out.println(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu").withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT).parse("31.02.2022"));

throws java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 31'

So you must use 'dd.MM.uuuu' to get the expected behaviour.

Comment: This is because with `yyyy` Java never comes around to deciding whether it’s 2022 BC or 2022 AD and hence not whether it’s a leap year and hence not the length of February. To me the good way to force Java to decide is to parse into a `LocalDate`.