# Pattern "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z" causes parsing exception where Jodatime did not

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

I am trying parse `ZonedDateTime`s from `Strings` in the following format:

`2017-08-10 16:48:37 -0500`

I had previously done so successfully using Jodatime's `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z")`.

I am trying to replace Jodatime with the Java Time API, and the same pattern no longer works.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-08-10 16:48:37 -0500", dtf);
```

results in the following exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-08-10 16:48:37 -0500' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=10, OffsetSeconds=-18000, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2017, MonthOfYear=8},ISO resolved to 16:48:37 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

What is the proper pattern to use for the format string in the Java Time API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should replace your `YYYY` part with `uuuu`

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    ZonedDateTime parsed = ZonedDateTime.parse("2017-08-10 16:48:37 -0500", dtf);
```

Comment: Interesting, what exactly is the difference between `year` (YYYY)  and `year-of-era` (uuuu)?

Comment: I can't explain it good myself. But pay attention that:
* u       year
* y       year-of-era 
* Y       week-based-year
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: **y** = year, **Y** = week year. If one uses a **week number** (1-53) the first half week of this year 2017 could be 52 whereas its **week year** would have been yesteryear 2016.

Comment: The [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java) explains it quite well. It's a breaking of established pattern to say the least.

Comment: And JodaTime indeed has its own pattern syntax, you cannot simply overtake Joda-patterns to the world of `java.time`-package (or even to old `SimpleDateFormat`-patterns). All three types of pattern definitions are different.