# Parse datetime without offset in OffsetDateTime java

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-format

Can I somehow parse a datetime that's without offset using `OffsetDateTime.parse(....)`

Java code:

```
DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS XXX");
OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-02-03 12:30:3000", FORMATTER);
```

I'm getting datetime as a `String` without offset, but need to parse it into `OffsetDateTime`, I know I need an offset here, but can I some how alter that `String` to insert default/dummy offset (maybe +00:00) & parse it using `OffsetDateTime`. The problem is that object has to be `OffsetDateTime`.

Comment: You can do this: `OffsetDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-02-03 12:30:3000", FORMATTER).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);`

Comment: @peter I got it half working by below code, but it produces 2017-02-03T12:30:30+11:00 not 2017-02-03 12:30:30+11:00  I want to get rid of T in between
        `DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-02-03 12:30:30.000", FORMATTER), OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset());`

Comment: Then you should format the parsed date afterwards using `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX").format(date)`

Comment: `12:30:3000`?? What is that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is to parse your string into a `LocalDateTime` and then convert:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
OffsetDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse("2017-02-03 12:30:30", formatter)
                                   .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

This gives an `OffsetDateTime` of `2017-02-03T12:30:30Z`, where `Z` means UTC or offset zero.

You *can*  parse directly into an `OffsetDateTime` if you want:

```
DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                  .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                  .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
                  .toFormatter();
OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-02-03 12:30:30", FORMATTER);
```

Finally, if you are required to use the formatter given in the question, altering the string to fit is of course an option. For example:

```
DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS XXX");
String fixedDateTimeString 
            = "2017-02-03 12:30:3000".replaceFirst("(\\d{2})0*$", "$1.000 +00:00");
OffsetDateTime date = OffsetDateTime.parse(fixedDateTimeString, FORMATTER);
```

As you can see, in the last example I have also kept the too many zeroes in the string I am using as a starting point, removing them in the same operation that appends the offset. The result is the same, `2017-02-03T12:30:30Z`.

**Edit:** `uuuu` or `yyyy` for year in the format pattern string? Since the year is always in the common era (Anno Domini), either works. `yyyy` is for year of era and would be right of there was an era designator (like AD or BC, format pattern letter `G`). `uuuu` is a signed year, where year 0 means 1 BCE, -1 means 2 BCE, etc. There’s more in [this question: `uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I achieved it by:

```
DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
OffsetDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse("2017-02-03 12:30:30", FORMATTER), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```