# Prevent SimpleDateFormat From Matching Strings With Extraneous Characters

Tags: java, date, format, simpledateformat

I'm using the following code to categorize whether or not the data type of text input is a date:

```
private boolean isDate(String val)
{
    //These are the only formats dates will have
    String[] formatList = {"MM/dd/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "MMM/dd/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy"};
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    dateFormat.

    //Loop through formats in formatList, and if one matches the string return true
    for (String str:formatList)
    {
        try
        {
            dateFormat.applyPattern(str);
            dateFormat.parse(val.trim());
        } catch (ParseException pe)
        {
            continue;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This method is called in a switch statement along with other function like isNumber, isDatetime, isVarchar2, etc.  When I pass the value '4/05/2013 23:54' which is a datetime, the SimpleDateFormat object successfully parses it.  I assume this is because it performs a regex match.  This means I have to call isDate after isDatetime or nothing will ever be categorized as a datetime.  Is there a simple way to get SimpleDateFormat to strictly match (ie, choke when there are extra characters)?

Comment: Your code won't even compile because you have a line like this: `dateFormat.` :)

Comment: *"I assume this is because it performs a regex match."* Bad assumption, because `SimpleDateFormat` doesn't use regex internally.

Comment: FYI, you are using troublesome old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API from Java8+ with only one pattern like so :

```
private boolean isDate(String dateString) {
    DateTimeFormatter format =
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                    "[M/d/uuuu][M-d-uuuu][MMM/d/uuuu][d-MMM-uuuu]"
            );
    try {
        LocalDate.parse(dateString, format);
        return true;
    }catch (DateTimeParseException e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

where `[M/d/uuuu][M-d-uuuu][MMM/d/uuuu][d-MMM-uuuu]` means to match either `M/d/uuuu` or `M-d-uuuu` or `MMM/d/uuuu` or `d-MMM-uuuu`

Comment: With `DateTimeFormatter`, you should use `uuuu` instead of `yyyy`.

Comment: quick search I found your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java I don't know about that @Andreas thank you for the information I will edit my answer and +1 for the detailed answer

Comment: @Andreas IMHO that’s only a mild “should”. In most often do that, but strictly speaking it depends on requirements, and in 99 % of situations it doesn’t matter in practice.. If `yyyy` works as it should in the question, it does in this answer too.

Comment: Hi @OleV.V. your comments makes me wait and search more about that

Comment: I think you meant for `catch` block to be `return false;`, otherwise return type `boolean` makes little sense. Also, it seems that OP expects `4/05/2013` to return true, which happens with `SimpleDateFormat`, but doesn't happen with your code. `dd` only parses 2-digit values. Use `d` to parse 1-digit values, i.e. the pattern should be `"[M/d/uuuu][M-d-uuuu][MMM/d/uuuu][d-MMM-uuuu]"`

Answer (score 2):

If you **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-), you'd see:

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. The method **may not use the entire text** of the given string.
>
> See the [`parse(String, ParsePosition)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse-java.lang.String-java.text.ParsePosition-) method for more information on date parsing.

The javadoc of the other method says:

> **Parameters:**
>
> `source` - The date/time string to be parsed
>
> `pos` - On input, the position at which to start parsing; **on output, the position at which parsing terminated, or the start position if the parse failed**.

So, to ensure the entire text matches the date format, use the second method and check the ending parse position.

This also has the beneficial effect of not using [exceptions for control flow](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/189222/202153).

```
private static boolean isDate(String val) {
    String trimmedVal = val.trim();
    
    //These are the only formats dates will have
    String[] formatList = {"MM/dd/yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "MMM/dd/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy"};
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat();
    dateFormat.setLenient(false);
    
    ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
    for (String str : formatList) {
        pos.setIndex(0);
        dateFormat.applyPattern(str);
        dateFormat.parse(trimmedVal, pos);
        if (pos.getIndex() == trimmedVal.length())
            return true; // full text parsed without error
    }
    return false;
}
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println(isDate("12/31/2018"));
System.out.println(isDate("12-31-2018"));
System.out.println(isDate("Dec/31/2018"));
System.out.println(isDate("31-Dec-2018"));
System.out.println(isDate("4/05/2013"));
System.out.println(isDate("4/05/2013 23:54"));
```

*Output*

```
true
true
true
true
true
false
```