# Cannot parse date time, issue with parsing pattern "ssSSS"

Tags: java, java-8

So I am trying to parse:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
TemporalAccessor parse = dateTimeFormatter.parse("20180521073438514");
```

And I receive the following error:
"Text '20180521073438514' could not be parsed at index 0"

But when I try to add sth that will separate "ss" and "SSS" it works:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMddHHmmss.SSS");
TemporalAccessor parse = dateTimeFormatter.parse("20180521073438.514");
```

Am I missing some kind of delimiter to separate "ss" and "SSS"?

Comment: By the way, it's [safer to use `u` instead of `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Java 8 which was fixed in Java 9. Have a look at the official bug report https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085

Comment: Ok, many thanks, somehow I did not manage to find this