# Changing LocalDateTimeFormat to include seconds and milliseconds

Tags: java, java-time

As per the requirement, my code is supposed to append date from a ZonedDateTime parameter, and Time from OffSetTime parameter into this format, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSz". However, i was not been able to achieve this

I have tried various ways , including the one below, using DateTimeFormatter.

```java
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-05-23T09:00:00-05:00");
OffsetTime offsetTime = OffsetTime.parse("08:59:00-05:00");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(zonedDateTime.toLocalDate(), offsetTime.toLocalTime());
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSz");
String finalDate = localDateTime.format(formatter);
```

I notice that :
- code is throwing "java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to extract value: class java.time.LocalDateTime" at localDateTime.format(formatter)

The expectation is to get the DateTime in String like so - "2019-05-23T08:59:00.000Z"

Any help appreciated, Thank you for your time.

Comment: A `LocalDateTime` doesn't have a time zone - it's not clear to me why you're using a `LocalDateTime` at all here... could you clarify how you want to combine `ZonedDateTime` and an `OffsetTime` anyway, in that they could have different offsets. (They don't in your example, but...)

Comment: I had to append zonedDateTime and offsetTime to a DateTime format, and i achieved it in the line `LocalDateTime.of(zonedDateTime.toLocalDate(), offsetTime.toLocalTime());` I don't care about localDateTime if i am able to parse it directly to the expected format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSz

Comment: That's the code, but does it accurately represent what you want to do? If you had a ZonedDateTime with an offset of UTC-8, and an OffsetTime with an offset of UTC+12, would that definitely still work? And why are you then formatting it to include a time zone, when there's no time zone associated with a LocalDateTime? You've given an example using Z, but that means UTC, which isn't the offset for *either* the date or the time.

Comment: sorry, i have edited over my previous comment to include more context. Also, for the moment i am a 100% sure that the offsetTime and zonedDateTime is going to be having the same TimeZone. I know its not a clean solution, and i am open to suggestions.

Comment: Okay - there's still the problem that you've started with offsets of UTC-5 and you're now ending up at UTC, which looks *really* unlikely to be a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, i was careless not to realize offsetTime.toLocalTime() do not consider the offset while resolving to localTime (that was how i thought toLocalTime works) .  Andreas's solution helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Four issues:

- `LocalDateTime` doesn't have any time zone information, so don't use it.
- Even if it did, your inputs only have a time zone *offset*, not a full time zone, so you format string cannot use `z`, as that requires a time zone *name*. Use `XXX` instead.
- Since the inputs are offset `-05:00` you shouldn't expect output with `Z` (Zulu), as that means `+00:00`, unless you also expect the time to be adjusted by 5 hours.
- The format pattern for year should use `uuuu`, not `yyyy`. See [`uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41177442/5221149)

Assuming you want to keep the time zone, change code to:

```
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2019-05-23T09:00:00-05:00");
OffsetTime offsetTime = OffsetTime.parse("08:59:00-05:00");
```

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = zonedDateTime.toLocalDate().atTime(offsetTime);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
System.out.println(offsetDateTime.format(formatter));
```

```
2019-05-23 08:59:00.000-05:00
```

If you instead want Zulu time, i.e. UTC, with the time adjusted, add the line to make the adjustment:

```
OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = zonedDateTime.toLocalDate().atTime(offsetTime)
                                .withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
System.out.println(offsetDateTime.format(formatter));
```

```
2019-05-23 13:59:00.000Z
```

Comment: Very knowledgeable, thank you. I might  include a warning in case the two offsets provided disagree. And I might find `OffsetDateTime offsetDateTime = zonedDateTime.toLocalDate().atTime(offsetTime).withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);` a bit simpler.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks, that is much better.

Comment: Thank you Andreas, Ole, Your solution worked for me.