# What's the time format of now() in Threeten?

Tags: android, date-formatting, zoneddatetime, threetenbp

I use `ThreeTen` module and when I print `ZonedDateTime.now()`, I get.

```
2019-07-11T22:43:36.564-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

What's the format of this?
I tried `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` and It says,

```
org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-07-11T22:43:36.564-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]' could not be parsed at index 23
```

So, after `SSS`, the `'Z'` part is incorrect.

What's the proper way to implement it?

This is my code:

```
val pstTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")).toString()
val timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
val mTime = LocalDateTime.parse(pstTime, timeFormatter).toString()
tv_pstTime.text = mTime
```

I want to parse it to the format like `Tuesday, July 2 5:15:01 P.M.`
How can I do that?

Comment: uuuu-MM-dd or yyyy-MM-dd?

Comment: you can see the `[` and `]` characters in the string. I think you need to add them to your format. Something like this: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS['Z']`

Comment: @Sony I was told that `uuuu` is better way.

Comment: @Sony [`uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java)

Comment: The quotes around `Z` would mean that there should be a literal `Z` in the date-time string. **Never** use this, it’s important. (Had there been a `Z` in your string, it would have been an offset, and you would have needed to parse it as such, not as a literal.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("....")`. Inside `.ofPattern("....")` you can have any pattern you want.

Like this:

```
val result = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"))
                          .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM d HH:mm:ss a"))
```

Output: `Thursday, July 11 23:51:21 PM`

Comment: You’ve looked through the questioner’s concrete questions and nicely spotted what s/he really needed. Truly great for a first Stack Overflow answer. Thanks and welcome here!