# Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor

Tags: java

I have following code

```
final String pattern = "MM/dd/YYYY";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
```

and while trying to parse `String date = "05/29/2003"`
I receive an exception:

```
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2023, DayOfMonth=29, MonthOfYear=5},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

What is the reason ?

Comment: `Y` is *week-based-year*, use `u` (*year*) or `y` (*year-of-era*)…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pattern is not correct instead, try this:

```
final String pattern = "MM/dd/uuuu"; // or "MM/dd/yyyy"
```

Formatting patterns are [case-sensitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity). The "yyyy" represents the year, while "YYYY" represents the week-based year. So you need to use `yyyy` or much better `uuuu` to solve your issue.

---

- [`uuuu` versus `yyyy` in `DateTimeFormatter` formatting pattern codes in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java)
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: Given your rep score, I’m surprised your answer includes neither an explanation nor a link to the relevant javadoc.

Comment: @VGR sometimes the answer explains itself :)

Comment: That Answer definitely needs the explanation. I added a bit more.